# Angular's $http.post to PHP empty $_POST

Tags: php, angularjs

I have the following scenario, I have an Angular variable called `contact` which is a JSON object that has the following members:

- Message
- Name
- Phone
- Email

I `console.log(contact)` and it logs the correct information, however once sent, `$_POST['contact']` results in an empty array. I was reading around and found that `$_POST['contact']` won't get populated like it would if it were an http request from jQuery. So I fixed it to the following:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
print_r($params);
```

And here is the Angular function:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(contact){
        console.log(contact);
        $scope.clearContactFormData();
        return $http.post('http://localhost/cpr_courses/app/methods/contact.php', contact).success(function(data){
            Materialize.toast(data, 4000);
        });
    }
```

Still the `print_r($params)` is empty. I have no idea what else is going on. Any help please?

**EDIT**

`console.log()` outputs the following:

```
Array[0]
email
:
"asd@asd.asd"
length
:
0
message
:
"rubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOBrubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOB"
name
:
"rubAWREIUVBAERWOBNATEIOB"
phone
:
"13345678"
```

and here is the network tab image:

[image: response headers]

Here's the declaration of the JSON object:

```
$scope.contact = {};
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
```

This is later put on on the form like this:

```
<form method="post" class="form-sl" role="form" name="contactForm" ng-submit="submitForm(contact)" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and later on, on each field like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="contact.email" autocomplete="off" ng-maxlength="50" length="50" required/>
```

Is that okay?

Comment: Look at your browser's network inspector what the actual raw HTTP request is. It has nothing to do with jQuery or Angular, PHP doesn't know or care which sent the request. What's important is the format of the request and how PHP handles different formats.

Comment: How exactly looks an output of console.log(contact)?

Comment: Check what the browser is sending in your network tab and verify it's what you think it is, and that it's valid json. Once you've verified that, echo `file_get_contents('php://input')` in php (without json_decode) and see what php's getting.

Comment: @codeninja I'm not fully sure but, could you please show how you did compose the contact object and how it looks like? because im not sure, but it doesn't seem like valid JSON, could you verify you did create it with `{}` and not with `[]`... that log seems quite weird

Comment: Content-Length:2 in the request headers implies that the browser is sending [] (2 bytes) to the server - probably because your `contact` variable is a keyed array. Given the length of the array is 0, Angular is probably not bothering to check if there's any data in it. Make your `contact` variable an Object instead

Comment: What does `$scope.clearContactFormData();` do? Can you put the console.log under that statement and see if you still get the contact?

Answer (score 4):

[The `$_POST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is a PHP commodity to automatically decode the body of the typical POST request sent by HTML forms. In other words, it expects one of these values in the `Content-Type` request header:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `multipart/form-data`

Since you have `application/json`, it remains empty.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: @codeninja You need to make client and server data formats match. I have no idea of which one you need and, if it's an Angular issue, it isn't my area of expertise.